# Javascript replace multiple apostrophes

Tags: javascript, replace

Can someone please tell me what i am doing wrong.....
I am trying to replace all apostrophes in a string
But it just wont do it no matter if i put escape slashes or such

```
str = str.replace(/'/g,"something else");
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you paste a sample string?

Comment: Works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/yG43n/ Post more of your relevant code.

Comment: Probably OP has some special unicode apostrophes instead of the common ones as well.

Comment: "this is' a test' string".replace(/'/g,"something else"); works fine

Comment: WTHELL.... i think i am going mad..... :D lol thanks everyone

Comment: Do I get the accept if I answer the new question "What the hell?" ;)

Answer (score 1):

You've probably figured it out by now or found an alternative.  I was searching for an answer that motivated me to create my profile on here to "vote" and give the person who had the answer that help me the credit.

I was using IE7 and the "g" Global denote wasn't working... it took bringing it down to fundamentals to get my replace all to work.  It was only replacing the first ' apostrophe when there were "n" amounts of ' in the string that I needed to escape.

```
var str = str.split(stringToBeReplaced).join(stringReplaceWith);
```

This is what ended up working for me.